# how to modify the html when we use twitter widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I am using twitter's widget in my website (i am making the website with the cms eZ publish).

So in my code i have this:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/MyTweeterAccount" data-widget-id="Mytweeter_Id">Tweets de @mytweeterAccount</a>
```

Script:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

So this work well, it provide me all tweets.
Now i would like to customize the html... Someone have an idea.
I guess i can't do it via the widget but i would like a confirmation because this is the first time i include twitter and maybe there is something i dont know.

Comment: You can change the theme in https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new

Answer (score 0):

To help other; we can't use the widget to modify the html. We have to use the API.